# Count values in I if value in F = "In Progress"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to sum the row values in column I if the row value in F = "In Progress"

Sum appears to be stuck at 0... is there anything I'm doing wrong?

```
=SUMIFS(I:I,F:F,"==""In Progress")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula should be =SUMIFS(I:I,F:F,"In Progress")